# Как удалить базу данных Postgres через ODBC?

Tags: sql, odbc, psql

Нужно удалить БД PostgreSQL используя ODBC драйвер. Пытаюсь вводить команды, но результата нет. PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-7) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Отключаю активные сессии:

```
my_db=> SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)  FROM pg_stat_activity  WHERE datname='my_db' AND pid<>pg_backend_pid();
 pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------
(0 строк)
```

Пытаюсь удалить БД:

```
my_db=> drop database my_db;
ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
```

Comment: В постгрессе нет команды смены текущей БД, задача нерешаема без закрытия текущего соединения и открытия нового.

Answer (score 1):

Вы из текущей БД пытаетесь её же и удалить:

**my_db**=> drop database **my_db**;

Отсюда и ошибка: `ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database`

Смените БД и повторите запрос.

Comment: При подключении через ODBC происходит подключение именно к заданной бд в этом и загвоздка у меня.

Comment: @shaman888 Тогда никак.

Comment: `подключение именно к заданной бд` - так задайте подключение к любой другой базе

Comment: подключайтесь к системной базе postgres